Flutter's FutureBuilder with methods within causing error
I'm using Flutter with the Provider plugin and I occurred in a error I cannot help myself out.
Inside my main.dart I have this "container"
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        MyWiget(),
        Consumer<LoaderProvider>(
          builder: (context, loader, child) {
            return Positioned.fill(
              child: loader.isLoading ? const OverlayLoadingView() : const SizedBox(),
            );
          },
        ),
        Consumer<NotificationProvider>(
          builder: (context, notification, child) {
            if (notification.message.isNotEmpty) {
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text(notification.message)),
                    )
                    .closed
                    .then(
                      (_) => notification.remove(),
                    );
              });
            }
            return const SizedBox();
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

and mywidget is:
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer3<HttpProvider, LoaderProvider, NotificationProvider>(
      builder: (context, http, loader, notification, child) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: http.get('...'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            loader.show();

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              notification.addException(snapshot.error!);
            }

            return Container();
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

The error I receive, every time the code hit loader.show() or notification.addException(snapshot.error!) is
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FOUNDATION LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching
notifications for LoaderProvider:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This _InheritedProviderScope<LoaderProvider?> widget cannot be
marked as needing to build because the framework is already in
the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as
needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its
ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed
because the framework builds parent widgets before children,
which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise,
the framework might not visit this widget during this build
phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called
was:
  _InheritedProviderScope<LoaderProvider?>
The widget which was currently being built when the offending
call was made was:
  FutureBuilder<MyClass>

Now, I can understand the error, but how to resolve it? Shouldn't the LoaderProvider and NotificationProvider be "isolated" inside the consumer, so the MyWidget should not render every time?
I'm using Flutter 3.19.6 and Dart 3.3.4

FutureBuilder(           future: http.get('...'), Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg


1.MyWidget Constructor Error: There's an error in the constructor of the MyWidget class where super.key is mentioned, which is invalid. To specify constructor arguments, you need to use this.key.
Blockquote
2.Loader Visibility Issue: loader.show() is placed inside the FutureBuilder, but it won't always be called. The builder function of
FutureBuilder doesn't execute on every frame, only when the status of
the future changes. If you want the loader to be shown always, move
loader.show() outside the FutureBuilder, or put it inside a setState
function so that it's called on every frame.
3.SnackBar Logic: There's SnackBar logic inside the Consumer<NotificationProvider>'s builder function, but this logic
won't execute because the return statement in the builder function is
const SizedBox(), which always returns a SizedBox widget. To display
the SnackBar, remove the return statement from the builder function
and directly add the SnackBar logic to the Stack's children.
4.Memory Leak: WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback is used to display the SnackBar. While this approach is correct, there's a
potential issue where the callback isn't removed. This can lead to
memory leaks. To remove the callback, use a StatefulWidget and remove
the callback in the dispose() method.

You can follow the structure like this:-
    class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer3<HttpProvider, LoaderProvider, NotificationProvider>(
      builder: (context, http, loader, notification, child) {
        // Start loading when MyWidget is built
        Future<void>.microtask(() {
          loader.show();
        });

        return FutureBuilder(
          future: http.get('...'),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            // Hide loader when future completes
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              Future<void>.microtask(() {
                loader.hide();
              });
            }

            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // Handle error
              notification.addException(snapshot.error!);
            }

            return Container();
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

    
    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              MyWidget(),
              Consumer<LoaderProvider>(
                builder: (context, loader, child) {
                  // Show loader when isLoading is true
                  return loader.isLoading ? const OverlayLoadingView() : const SizedBox();
                },
              ),
              Consumer<NotificationProvider>(
                builder: (context, notification, child) {
                  if (notification.message.isNotEmpty) {
                    // Show SnackBar if there's a message
                    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                          .showSnackBar(
                            SnackBar(content: Text(notification.message)),
                          )
                          .closed
                          .then(
                            (_) => notification.remove(),
                          );
                    });
                  }
                  return const SizedBox();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }


Hello @devraj and thanks for your answer. The problem remains because when the code hit loader.hide() the same error appear

Hmmm, The error you're encountering indicates that a call to setState() or markNeedsBuild() is happening during the build process. This typically occurs when trying to update the state of a widget during its build phase, which is not allowed.
In your case, it seems like the issue is with calling loader.show() and loader.hide() inside the MyWidget build function. These calls should be moved out of the build method to avoid updating the state during the build phase.

Nope, It does not work

@devray, I don't know about the downvote. Anyway, even you update answer is not working.

@Valerio, Same error ?

Exactly. Seeing there is not much on the topic, I start to think it's my whole idea wrong. I'll refactor to Statefulwidget

That's right. But I thought there might be some condition or architecture you are following here.
